# test if return true if grep on output has string in one line

Tags: shell, grep, exit

I just want to return true or false if a service is running.  Here is where I'm at, not first try or last but current at writing:

```
service iptables status | grep -qi "not running"
```

The sdtout for `service iptables status` when it's stopped is `iptables: Firewall is not running` When I run what I came up with is nothing on a new line, which I guess is not unexpected as 0 is true and non-0 is false.  So, I need to test to ensure it works, but I'm unsure what to do.  Here is the try:

```
service iptables status | grep -qi "not running" || echo "stopped"
```

so when the service is stopped I expected to see `stopped` but I didn't get anything but a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
service iptables status | grep -qi "not running" && echo "stopped"
```

You just need to replace `||` with `&&`. One confusing thing about shell scripting is that 0 is true and any other number is false, opposite to most other languages. This is just because programs generally return a 0 for success.

I also need to add an `2>&1` after status as `service` on my distro outputs to stderr, doesn't look like its a problem for you though.

Comment: IMHO better to think of it as *exit status* and not boolean `true` / `false`. Thus `if exit status == EXIT_SUCCESS then …`. Grep also only uses `1` for non-match. Anything > 1 is error code.

Comment: Sure, but sooner or later you have to use `true` or `false` builtins for something. Although `succeed` and `fail` may be more intuitive names for them :)

Comment: No. `true` and `false` are boolean values. My point, perhaps poorly conveyed, is that *exit status* is not a boolean value. It evaluates to `true` and `false`, but the value falls between 0 and 255. We also have `((1))` and `((0))`.

Answer (score 1):

If `grep` does *not* see a match, it will return a non-zero code.  A return of `0` means that a match *was* found.  You probably want:

```
service iptables status | grep -qi 'not running' && echo 'Stopped'
```